# AS3 - How to animate all movie clips in the stage if i click a certain button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi have been reading on this great website, here is what i want to accomplish,
on this certain page in the app im doing, there are movie clips (buttons, texts, menus) , now what i want is if i click this "close" button, i want everything to animate e.g shrink one by one. Question: Is there a great way to code this efficiently, and not coding it one by one e.g menu_mc.gotoAndPlay("out");, text_mc.gotoAndPlay("out"); image.gotoAndPlay("out"); ...something like that. Sorry im so new to this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Shrink" independently or as a whole?

Comment: thanks for the reply Vesper, Shrink independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the [DisplayList](http://www.adobe.com/jp/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html), and call your method...

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
    var obj:* = this.getChildAt(i);
    if (obj is MovieClip) {
        obj.gotoAndPlay("out");
    }
}
```

Or you could animate with an animation library (such as [Greensock](https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as))...

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
    var obj:* = this.getChildAt(i);
    TweenLite.to(obj, .35, {scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, delay:0.25*i});
}
```

Or you could reference an `Array` for the objects you want to animate; a superior choice (if your objects aren't in the same container).

```
var a:Array = [menu_mc, text_mc, image];

for (var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    TweenLite.to(a[i], .35, {scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, delay:0.25*i});
}
```